# WebView and httpClient

Tags: java, android, single-sign-on, httpclient

In android, I am trying to integrate Single-SignOn(SAML). For athentication webview is used and it prompt the user to enter username and password. After varify it returns the token embedded in html body.Now how can i get that token out of html body If I USE httpClient and making the webview cookie sync so that it work fine on HttpClient.